# PHP - Can unset() stop the loop?

Tags: php

I'm trying to `remove all the element of PHP array` if `the value equals zero`

I'm trying lots of way and reading `the unset document` but I'm still stuck at there

My `HTML page`. I have `9 input type = number` with `name = count[]`

```
<form action="send.php" method="post">
    <div>
        <input type="number" name="count[]" id="count-1" value="0" min="0" max="99">
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="number" name="count[]" id="count-2" value="0" min="0" max="99">
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="number" name="count[]" id="count-3" value="0" min="0" max="99">
    </div>
    ...
    <div>
        <input type="number" name="count[]" id="count-9" value="0" min="0" max="99">
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

And this is my `send.php` file

I mean if an element of `$count` equals `zero`, I will `remove` that element from array. But it's seem like somethings was wrong.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST)) {
    $count = $_POST["count"];
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($count); $i++) {
        if (0 == (int) $count[$i])
            unset($count[$i]);
    }
}
```

This is my `POST data`

```
Array
(
    [count] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [3] => 0
            [4] => 0
            [5] => 0
            [6] => 0
            [7] => 0
            [8] => 0
        )

    [submit] => submit
)
```

And this is the data of `$count array` I have been resulted. I don't know why the `if statement` not working with some of last elements.

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 1
    [6] => 0
    [7] => 0
    [8] => 0
)
```

I'm using `PHP 8`

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of iterating through the array and checking each value, you can use `array_filter` to remove zeros. By default `array_filter` removes empty values, one of which is `0` and `'0'` in PHP.
Here's a working [demo](https://3v4l.org/iqrui) of using `array_filter`.

```php
$count = array_filter($_POST["count"]);
```

Your current implementation won't work because you are using `count` inside the for statement. Since you're `unset`-ing the array values the count will be less for the next iterator of the loop.

A simple example is like this; the first iteration `count` is 7. After two iterations we unset a value from the array. In the next iteration `count` will return 6. With each `unset` you're decreasing the value returned by `count` while you're increasing `$i`. A fix for this would be to store the initial `count` before the loop so it's a fixed value during the loop. Here's a working [demo](https://3v4l.org/9mHDt) or that.

```php
$numOfCounts = count($count);

for ($i = 0; $i < $numOfCounts; $i++) {
    if (0 == (int) $count[$i])
        unset($count[$i]);
}
```

Comment: It's working Sir. And, did you know why all my codes above are not working?

Comment: Just edited my answer and added an explanation for that. 

Comment: Oh, I got it...

Answer (score 0):

Just using php filter function
(https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)[filter]

```
$count = [];
if (isset($_POST["count"])
   $count = array_filter(function($a){ return $a !== 0; }, $_POST["count"]);

print_r($count);
```

Comment: “Do it this way instead” does not answer the question of why it doesn’t work with the code in the question - please address this also. Note the solution can be significantly simplified as the function is unnecessary since it’s just a truthy check (also the function provided won’t work as the values are strings, not integers).